# SQL Distinct Count with Group By

Tags: sql, ms-access, distinct

My table in this issue has three columns: Player, Team and Date_Played.

```
Player         Team         Date_Played
John Smith     New York     2/25/2014
Joe Smith      New York     2/25/2014
Steve Johnson  New York     2/25/2014
Steph Curry    Orlando      2/25/2014
Frank Anthony  Orlando      2/26/2014
Brian Smith    New York     2/26/2014
Steve Johnson  New York     2/27/2014
Steph Curry    New York     2/28/2014
```

I know how to get a list of distinct team names or dates played, but what I'm looking for is a query that will group by Team and count the number of distinct Team & Date combinations. So the output should look like this:

```
Team          Count
New York      4
Orlando       2
```

So far I have:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Tm, Count(Date_Played) AS Count
FROM NBAGameLog
GROUP BY NBAGameLog.[Tm];
```

But this gives me the total amount of records grouped by date.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This query has been tested in Access 2010:

```sql
SELECT Team, Count(Date_Played) AS Count
FROM
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT Team, Date_Played
        FROM NBAGameLog
    ) AS whatever
GROUP BY Team
```

Answer (score 10):

A bit less code:

```
SELECT Team, Count(distinct Date_Played) AS Count 
FROM NBAGameLog 
GROUP BY Team
```

It does Show the same execution plan as the first answer.

Answer (score 2):

If I've understood right you, you are looking for a query like this:

```
SELECT x.Team, count(*)
FROM 
    (SELECT Team, Date_Played
     FROM NBAGameLog
     GROUP BY Team, Date_Played) AS x
GROUP BY x.Team
```

Comment: Access says: "You tried to execute a query that does not include the specified expression 'Count' as part of an aggregate function."

Comment: This actually gives me the same results I originally had. I essentially am looking for the number of days each team has played on. So in the above example, New York played on 4 distinct days.

Comment: I would like to upvote this, but the correct statement is `select x.TM, count(*)`.

Comment: Have I corrected it like you say? I think the result is the same, but I don't know what you want to say

Comment: Your query is okay except that the field name is `Team`, not `Tm`.

Comment: lol, I've named it Tm because he named it Tm too, but I thought that was clear. Thx for comments, I'll correct it ;)

Comment: For the record, the spelling of the field wasn't the issue. When I ran your answer the first time it was giving me the same as my original query. But your updated one also works...either way thank you both.